# Why can not I use many play/pause buttons in one HTML page?

Tags: html, button, audio

In this [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio) tutorial, I can make audio play/pause button. But when I put many buttons in one page. All buttons play the same sound track. It is the sound track of the first button only. I've changed the link of the audio *src* many times in all buttons I still having the same issue.

I know the answer is simple but I don't know it. Is the issue due to the variable *my* or due to the function or something else?

Thank you very much,

I use the following code to create a button:

```html
<audio id="myAudio" preload="none"
    <audio id="myAudio"

 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type='audio/mp4'>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
 Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
<script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var my

Audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");   if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();   } else {
    myAudio.pause();   } }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple elements with the same `id`:

```
<audio id="myAudio" ...
<audio id="myAudio" ...
```

After all, when you get that element, which one do you expect to use?:

```
document.getElementById("myAudio")
```

Use different `id` values for your elements.

```
<audio id="myFirstAudio" ...
<audio id="mySecondAudio" ...
```

And get references to them by identifying them separately:

```
var myFirstAudio = document.getElementById("myFirstAudio");
var mySecondAudio = document.getElementById("mySecondAudio");
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have different audio files, you have to create an audio object for each of them, with different IDs, and then adress those IDs with your buttons.

```
<audio id="myAudio1" preload="none" 
    ...>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio2" preload="none"
    ...>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio3" preload="none"
    ...>
</audio>
```